# 2D array from C# to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I've retrieved data from database, and I've stored it in a 2D array (jagged).

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=COMP7;Initial Catalog=GK_Practice;User ID=sa;Password=SQLEXPRESS");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from employee";
con.Open();

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int rowcount=0, columncount;

while(rd.Read())
{
    rowcount++;            
}

columncount = rd.FieldCount;
rd.Close();
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

string[][] str=new string[rowcount][];
int i = 0;
while(rd.Read())
{
   str[i] = new string[columncount];
   for (int j = 0; j < columncount; j++)
   {
       str[i][j] = rd.GetValue(j).ToString();
   }
   i++;
}

Label2.Text = str[1][1].ToString();
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize((object)str);
Response.Write(json);
rd.Close();
con.Close();
```

Now I've serialized this so as to pass as JSON, to be used at the client (browser). When I say `Response.Write(json);` it gives the following output:

```
 [["1","John","xyz","12000"],["2","Mike","pqr","15000"],["3","Nick","fjdu","18000"],["4","Brad","wee","22000"]]
```

But I want this data to be stored in JavaScript variable (say \var x) and use it as x[0][1].

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a c# function and called it from client side. the same code you will have to write in GetData function and that will return string as you have serialize using `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
var Json = <%= GetData(); %>
```

That will render page like this,

```
var Json = [["1","John","xyz","12000"],["2","Mike","pqr","15000"],["3","Nick","fjdu","18000"],["4","Brad","wee","22000"]]
```

And you can access values like `Json[0][0]` would return 1.

**Code behind**

```
public partial class Somepage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=COMP7;Initial Catalog=GK_Practice;User ID=sa;Password=SQLEXPRESS");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from employee";
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int rowcount=0, columncount;

        while(rd.Read())
        {
            rowcount++;            
        }

        columncount = rd.FieldCount;
        rd.Close();
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string[][] str=new string[rowcount][];
        int i = 0;
        while(rd.Read())
        {
           str[i] = new string[columncount];
           for (int j = 0; j < columncount; j++)
           {
               str[i][j] = rd.GetValue(j).ToString();
           }
           i++;
        }

        Label2.Text = str[1][1].ToString();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = js.Serialize((object)str);
        rd.Close();
        con.Close();

        return json;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Just to feel you this is code behind
    }
}
```

**Clint side (Javascript)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Json = <%= GetData(); %>

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: 1) Are you using mvc or webform application ? 2) Make sure function returns correct json as string format. 3) is it rendering correct as expected?

Comment: i'm using asp.net web site. As said if i say Response.Write(json); then it gives proper output on browser, i.e. [["1","John","xyz","12000"],["2","Mike","pqr","15000"],["3","Nick","fjdu","18000"],["4","Brad","wee","22000"]]

Comment: `var Json = <%= GetData(); %>` not a good code. What if `GetData()` returns null! the page will be doomed.

Comment: @Rashmin Javiya : Thanx for posting the code.

I tried the following on client:
 <script  type="text/javascript" >
    
        alert('0');
        var Json = <% GetData(); %>
        alert('1');
        alert(Json[0][1]);
        alert('2');
</script>

but when run, i'm only getting alert for 0 and 1...
Neither getting alert for Json[0][1] nor for alert 2

Comment: @Rashmin Javiya:  Note that i just used <% GetData() %> i.e. = sign not used.

When I used it, the page rendered: 
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected.

And < % =GetData %> was highlighted

Comment: Remove ;(semicolon) from - <%= GetData(); %>

Comment: @Rashmin Javiya: Hey it worked after i removed the semicolon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");
    sb.Append(string.Format("var jsonObj ={0}", json));
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jsonObjVar", sb.ToString());
```

then in your dom you will have the global variable name jsonObj.

Answer (score 0):

Depending you are using MVC razor or ASP, the syntax will change a bit on view.
Using MVC razor you simply has to put the string into model variable (into controller) and access into the page.

```
var json = @model.MyString;
```